# Django creating a web site with fully coded html

Tags: html, django, web

I have a project where I have to design the web page and create a login system for the user. I wrote a fully build HTML, CSS and javascript web design and now I have to connect with Django to build a login system. I know it's a bit a simple question but is it so hard to build the templates for fully made HTML?
I searched everywhere for such an example like that but in every video I watch people starting the web design from to top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to go through each of your pages and replace the reference links with `{% static 'file' %}` and any of the page links with the `{% url 'home' %}`

Other than that importing your own template will be pretty easy, once the django project is up and running.

You will just need to look out for references from the models or the views, and make sure they get put in as well.